# Java Axis Webservice parsing error

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

My server is a Drupal website with the services module and soap server.
The webservice allows user to login and create or retrieve news.

I have tested the service with SOAPUi and it works fine. 
The wsdl is generated by the soap server and it returns a struct to the client.

I have used axis to generate a stub class. 
I use it to create a client but when I invoke a method "`serviceStub.user_soap_login(login);`" to my webservice I got this error

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Expected a text token, got START_ELEMENT.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,275]
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at soap_server.Soap_server_serviceStub.fromOM(Soap_server_serviceStub.java:5035)
    at soap_server.Soap_server_serviceStub.user_soap_login(Soap_server_serviceStub.java:1027)
    at soap_server.test.main(test.java:67)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.exception.OMStreamingException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Expected a text token, got START_ELEMENT.
```

Thanks

Comment: which axis2 module version are you using ?

Comment: I have fixed the problem with HTTPConstants.CHUNKED at false :)